# MySQL on duplicate update not updating

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, duplicates

I'm attempting to run the following statement:

```
INSERT into table (col1,col2,col3,col4)
    VALUES ('1','2','3','4') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3 = '3'
```

According to many of the examples in the forums, this should work on the record currently in the system, but when I execute this and run a select afterwards, col3 is unaffected. I get no errors when running the insert statement. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get an error if you run the `insert` without the `on duplicate key`?  If not, double check if your table has a key (aka unique constraint.)

Comment: Yup, I do get an error running the insert by itself. Primary key duplicate.

Comment: @GeekGrid . . . What is the primary key?  Is there, for instance, a unique constraint that includes `col3`?  My guess is that the update is attempted but it fails a test.

Answer (score 0):

See below, created a table called TAB with unique key on c3.

1. First insert, its a smooth insert.
2. Second insert, the value at c3 is updated to 4, since Im having a unique key on c3.
3. Third insert, its again smooth, because this time its (1,2,3,4) which is not a duplicate because the table only has (1,2,4,4)
4. Fourth insert, bombed, because the insert value "3" is a duplicate and when trying to update, the update value "4" for c3 is also duplicate.

-

```
mysql> desc tab;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| c1    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| c2    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| c3    | int(11) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| c4    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from tab;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from tab;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT into tab (c1,c2,c3,c4)     VALUES ('1','2','3','4')      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c3 = '4';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from tab;
+------+------+------+------+
| c1   | c2   | c3   | c4   |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |
+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT into tab (c1,c2,c3,c4)     VALUES ('1','2','3','4')      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c3 = '4';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> select * from tab;
+------+------+------+------+
| c1   | c2   | c3   | c4   |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    4 |    4 |
+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT into tab (c1,c2,c3,c4)     VALUES ('1','2','3','4')      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c3 = '4';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from tab;
+------+------+------+------+
| c1   | c2   | c3   | c4   |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    4 |    4 |
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |
+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT into tab (c1,c2,c3,c4)     VALUES ('1','2','3','4')      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c3 = '4';
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '4' for key 'c3_u'
mysql> select * from tab;
+------+------+------+------+
| c1   | c2   | c3   | c4   |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    4 |    4 |
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |
+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```